# Array group and some operations

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have db data like:

```
date, storage, bandwidth, cost
```

I can have entries like:

```
2013-10-24, 1, 0, 0.55; 
2013-10-25, 1, 0, 0.50; 
2013-10-25, 1, 0, 0.25; 
2013-10-25, 0, 1, 0.50;
```

I grab the data from db and make a foreach. I will get of course 4 rows. I will need to group data like this:

This means that on 2013-10-24 I had storage cost of 0.55
And on 2013-10-25 I had storage cost of 0.75 and bandwidth cost of 0.50

I made a function:

```
    public function sortCostByDay($array, $key)
    {
        $return = array();
        foreach($array as $v)
        {
            $storage = $bandwidth = $total = 0;

            if($v['storage'] == 1)
            {
                $storage += $v['cost'];
                $total += $storage;
            }
            if($v['bandwidth'] == 1)
            {
                $bandwidth += $v['cost'];
                $total += $bandwidth;
            }

            $return[$v[$key]][] = array('storage' => $storage, 'bandwidth' => $bandwidth, 'total' => $total);
        }

        return $return;
    }
```

This will group my initial array by $key. The $key is the date.

So I end up having this:

```
'2013-10-24' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'storage' => 0.55
          'bandwidth' => 0
          'total' => 0.55
'2013-10-25' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'storage' => 0.50
          'bandwidth' => 0
          'total' => 0.50
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          'storage' => 0.25
          'bandwidth' => 0
          'total' => 0.50
      2 => 
        array (size=3)
          'storage' => 0
          'bandwidth' => 0.50
          'total' => 1
```

I can`t figure out how to make it be something like:

```
'2013-10-24' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'storage' => 0.55
          'bandwidth' => 0
          'total' => 0.55
'2013-10-25' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'storage' => 0.75
          'bandwidth' => 0.50
          'total' => 1.25
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: array_reduce with foreach by ref perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

you can take the data from mySQL already grouped. Assuming you use mySQL database and your fields for date and cost are called day_date and day_cost:

```
SELECT day_date, SUM(day_cost) as storage FROM your_table GROUP BY day_date
```

it will produce an array:

```
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'day_date' => '2013-10-24'
      'storage' => 0.55
```

i would optimize your data table to save only the day and the cost of storage and bandwidth instead of flags and one cost field. now you have 4 fields and in my case you would have only 3:

```
day_date (date), storage (float), bandwidth (float)
```

Comment: I kinda have the date in mysql stored as timestamp and then on my inital foreach I make it as a date.

Comment: +1, but if you want to separate the storage cost from the bandwidth cost you might need something like `SELECT day_date, SUM(storage*day_cost), SUM(bandwidth*day_cost) FROM your_table GROUP BY day_date`

Comment: then just change the the structure of your table ;) you don't really need to store timestamps, because PHP has DateTime class to work with dates, f.e. modify('+ 5 minutes')

Comment: i think that the 0/1 are only the flags, not the amount of storage or bandwidth

Comment: So this will not bring me afterall at something like...an array for storage and one for bandwidth for the same date?

Comment: your current data table structure is very poor for such operations. if you changed it to one i offer, you could get that array right from the mySQL

Comment: This will mean to update the row for that specific user too many times. For storage and for bandwidth. I might have 100 queries/second.

Comment: update is almost equal to create, so i don't see here a problem.